# Extension for UITABLEVIEWCELL not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift-extensions

I had created extension :

```
 public extension UITableViewCell {
        /// Generated cell identifier derived from class name
        static func cellIdentifier() -> String {
            return String(describing: self)
        }
      
        var indexPath:IndexPath?{
               return tableView?.indexPath(for: self)
        }
      
        var tableView: UITableView? {
               var view = superview
               while let v = view, v.isKind(of: UITableView.self) == false {
                   view = v.superview
               }
               return view as? UITableView
        }
    }
```

I am trying to use extension in uitableviewcell class :

```
func setup(viewModel: ViewModelClass) {       
        if indexPath != nil {
            print("indexpath") 
        }else {
            print("nil")  // But it always gives nill.
        }
}
```

I want to fetch section and row for index in uitableviewcell.

Comment: How do you call `setup(viewModel:`?

Comment: Most likely the cell is not part of a `UITableView` yet. By the way, you should probably use `is` instead of `isKind(of:)`.

Comment: setup() is protocol method which is called from cellForRowAt indexPath

Comment: This kind of *retain cycle* is pretty weird. The cell is part of the table view, not the other way round. And the view hierarchy math to get the table view reference is even weirder.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this extension. I use this in project to get indexPath and tableView in UITableViewCell subclasses and it works totally fine.

```
private extension UIResponder {
    func next<T: UIResponder>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return next as? T ?? next?.next(type)
    }
}

extension UITableViewCell {

    var tableView: UITableView? {
        return next(UITableView.self)
    }

    var indexPath: IndexPath? {
        return tableView?.indexPath(for: self)
    }
}
```